# React native navigate like click post in Instagram

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-flatlist

I am making an album app with react native and want to make `FlatList` with images like Instagram. When clicks item of `FlatList`, it will navigate to the same item in another screen with different `FlatList`. How to do this?

1. when click image JS

[image]

2. navigate to it in another screen

[image]

My code:

```
const RenderItemList = ({item, index}) => {
   return (
     <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate('detail')}>
     <View key={index} style={[index%3!==0 ? {paddingLeft:2} : {paddingLeft:0}, {marginBottom: 2}]}>  
     
      <Image style={{width: sizeOfImage, height: sizeOfImage}}
      source={{uri : item.uri}}
      />
     </View>
     </Pressable>         
)}
```

Comment: Could you specify your question? What is blocking you?

Comment: I got the answer! thank for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `initialScrollIndex` prop from the `Flatlist` API. Pass the index as route params to other screen and set `initialScrollIndex` to that index.

Example below

```js
<FlatList
  data={sampleImages}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
  numColumns={3}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <Pressable
      style={{ width: EachWidth, height: EachWidth }}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', { initialScroll: index })}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: item.download_url }}
        style={{ width: EachWidth, height: EachWidth }}
      />
    </Pressable>
  )}
/>
```

On other screen,

```js
<FlatList
  data={sampleImages}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
  initialScrollIndex={route.params.initialScroll || 0} // Use here
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={{ width: ScreenWidth, height: ScreenWidth }}>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: item.download_url }}
        style={{ width: ScreenWidth, height: ScreenWidth }}
      />
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/scrollsnap)

Comment: brilliant answer, thanks